# Vue3 dynamic components

Tags: vuejs3, inertiajs

I am trying to include a sidebar menu based on what is passed from the controller. For example, the string "TestMenu" or "UserMenu" is passed. The component however, is not being included. Devtools is showing me that `menu` has been set to either `TestMenu` or `UserMenu`, so that works. Using `<TestMenu />` also works. But not the dynamic component.

```
<template>

    <component :is="menu"/>

</template>

<script setup>
import TestMenu from './Menus/TestMenu.vue';
import UserMenu from './Menus/UserMenu.vue';

defineProps({
    menu: String
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason that doesn't work so I suggest doing it this way

```
function computeComponent(component) {
    switch (component) {
        case 'TestMenu':
            return TestMenu;
        case 'UserMenu':
            return UserMenu;
        default:
            return {};
    }
}
```

then to use it do this

```
<component :is="computeComponent(menu)" />
```

make sure you import those components